# How to change the Content Node for a CCSrollView in SpriteBuilder

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

I'm building a game that requires levels. These levels, so that they all fit onto one page I have had to add them to a CCScrollView. This view loads automatically, as I have set in the SpriteBuilder App. The CCSrollView has been added in the MainScene.ccb file, and the content node for the scroll view is Level.ccb. What I'm trying do is have a button that is in the Level.ccb that changes the scene/content node to a level which is called Gameplay.ccb. I've tried writing the code to change the scene in the MainScene.m and Level.m files in Xcode. However these bring up an error. I'm still learning to code, so sorry if the question has been asked or has a really easy solution

```
- (void)levelOne {

    CCScene *gameplayScene = [CCBReader loadAsScene:@"Gameplay"];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:gameplayScene];

}
```

This piece of code is how i would switch the scene without the scrollview

If you do not understand what my problem is and would like the code send me a message and i will email you the source code

Thanks!

Comment: do not use a ccscrollview for that, the scrolling is supposed to be user-initiated and it's probabaly not what you want. There's no contentNode replacement method either. Instead just use sub file, assign it to an ivar and in code remove the existing node, the load another ccb and add it.

Comment: is there a way that i could use a slider to move the camera view along a scene?